# Constructive way to advise poster on their approach

Tags: discussion, comments, new-users

This is related but I think not identical to: [Is it appropriate to caution a poster about their tone?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324289/is-it-appropriate-to-caution-a-poster-about-their-tone/324354#324354)

I (and another user) have been engaged with a new poster whose question was phrased as "why is R doing [this] wrong"? I think I eventually figured out what their real confusion was, but there was a lot of back-and-forth along the lines of "but R is wrong". I would love to suggest to them that (1) saying that "R is doing it wrong" is likely to antagonize high-rep users (and thus reduce one's chances of getting help), (2) it's more constructive to ask (and think) along the lines of, "this seems to be wrong, but surely an R function that's been used by hundreds of thousands of people for two decades can't be wrong, what am I missing"?

I'm afraid of coming off as condescending. Suggestions for how to handle the situation/phrase a comment?

(I wasn't sure whether to provide the link, for fear of the meta effect, but [upvoted answers to this question suggest it's OK to do so](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327134/when-is-it-appropriate-to-unleash-the-meta-effect), so [here it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51862867/non-understandable-behavior-ccf-function-stats-package/51864433?noredirect=1#comment90681574_51864433).)

Comment: What is your intended relevance in mentioning "high rep users"? "Low rep" users can be antagonised by a lack of information too, as can "middle rep" users.

Comment: Just meant to indicate that we are both reasonably experienced, have a sense of SO norms, etc... edited.

Comment: _I'm afraid of coming off as condescending._? Why? You don't know these people. As long as you're not rude it really doesn't matter. If they interpret your comment as condescending, move on. You don't need that in your life.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The answer seems to be in your question:

> (2) it's more constructive to ask (and think) along the lines of, "this
>   seems to be wrong, but surely...

Paraphrasing this in an answer:

> This may not be intuitive, but...

Or something like:

> While the behaviour you see may seem incorrect, ...

Or even:

> Your code is not applying the logic you expect because ...

Don't try and change OP's attitude. A single answer or comment isn't going to change a person's attitude to programming, or life. What you can do is write a meaningful answer that is helpful to the community. And to OP too, if they are willing to listen.

Comments which don't help clarify the problem or answer can be safely ignored. Don't feel the need to respond.

In short, answer the question, not the questioner.

Comment: Yes, this is what I do all the time.

Comment: _"Don't try and change OP's attitude. A single answer or comment isn't going to change a person's attitude to programming, or life."_ If not us then who will?

Comment: *"If not us then who will?"* - Not our problem.  Seriously.  Down-vote and move on.

Comment: @StephenC: I take a different view. Ultimately, as members of our industry, it does affect us and it is our problem. To some extent. Maybe. Ignoring it for decades, taking no responsibility for trying to change it, is why the industry has become saturated with whatever-you-want-to-call-it. Slopey shoulder is ultimately self-defeating I guess is my point

Comment: Well good luck to you.  Unfortunately, StackExchange (the company) does not see this as the community's role.  They would prefer us to be welcoming.

Comment: @StephenC That you think that helping people understand how to ask good questions, be polite, and not turn off other people with an antagonistic tone isn't welcoming, says rather a lot.  Saying that you'd rather refuse to engage with people at all, and feel that that's more welcoming them helping them, indicates that you don't seem to understand what the word means.

Comment: @Servy - The problem is the "welcoming-ness" is in the eye the person being welcomed.  (Indeed, this is the metric that the StackExchange corporate is using ... in their surveys, etc)  Helping someone to be a good citizen when they are not interested in learning is unwelcoming in their eyes.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, Re: `If not us then who will?` The way I think of it, will changing OP's attitude help future visitors? Given the wide-ranging and multi-faceted attitudes out there in the world, I don't think it's useful to adapt answers to include user-specific attitude-changing / preachy elements. Maybe in a chat room, but not on a Q&A site.

Comment: @jpp: Though I'm not necessarily agreeing or disagreeing with it right now, that's a strong argument.

Comment: @StephenC Interesting that you're very explicitly saying that people asking questions don't need to be welcoming at all, and that it's perfectly okay for them to be rude and inconsiderate to others, and that it's only people trying to help them that can *possibly* be unwelcoming.

Comment: It's also interesting that you think that literally every single question author considers literally anyone telling them how to improve their question, regardless of how they do it, to be unwelcome.  I know for a fact that that's not true, as many have said that they're very grateful for people helping them ask better questions.  *You* are in fact being very unwelcoming to lots of people by explicitly telling them to leave our community for trying to help others.

Comment: 1)  People asking questions are not the ones who need to be welcoming.  When someone knows at your front door, you welcome them.  They don't welcome you.  2) I am not saying they don't need to be polite, civil, read the guidance on how to ask appropriate questions.  But if they don't, it is not our job to teach them.  I don't know whose job it is.  But since >>our<< attempts to educate people are perceived as unwelcoming, and (per management's view) it is the  perception that counts, we have little choice but to wash our hands.  Down-vote and move on.

Comment: @StephenC People answering questions don't own SO.  It's not their house.  By that logic SO employees are the only people that need to be welcoming.  In actuality *everyone* should be acting professionally towards *everyone*, it's not up to question authors to do what they want and people answering or commenting to be the only ones with a burden to act appropriately.  And yes, it's no one's *job* to teach them how to act appropriately, but people are *welcome* and *encouraged* to help others if they want to.

Comment: Your assertion that no one should help anyone else, ever, is, frankly, extremely unwelcoming and inconsiderate.  Have some empathy for others, would you.  SO didn't say that everyone's attempt to help everyone, ever, is inappropriate.  Certain things that people were doing were inappropriate; the goal is to have people help others *more effectively*, not *not at all*.  There is of course some disagreement between the community and SO as to what is and isn't appropriate, but that doesn't mean *no one* should be helping *anyone*, *ever*.  Even SO isn't saying that.

Comment: @Servy - Frankly, you keep on putting words into my mouth.  I am not going to debate you anymore.  This is about teaching people how to behave, not about helping them.

Comment: @StephenC Teaching is one way to help someone, it's of course not the only way.  That said, the question is about telling people that they've structured their question in such a way that it's not conducive to a good answer, and that it's likely to turn off others from answering as a result.  That's not really teaching (at most you could argue that it's teaching someone how to ask questions better).  Either way, that *is* helping, whether you consider that teaching or not.

Comment: @StephenC I don't think a quick comment about an alternative wording of their request is a waste of time. `You probably didn't intend it this way but your question "Why is R doing it wrong?" may come off as critical. Perhaps something like, "This seems wrong, please help me understand..." would be less off putting and attract more answers`. If it's offered politely, it's not against SO's rules... and if OP doesn't take it well, that's not our problem... at least we tried. SO staff isn't going to fix this issue... we, the users, must because we see it more often and there's more of us.

Comment: @StephenC `This is about teaching people how to behave, not about helping them.` This is about teaching them how to behave *so they are more likely to be helped*.

Comment: It is not a matter of "attitude" is is a matter of problem solving techniques. The asker's approach is an impediment to them & they are mischaracterizing the problem. It is helpful to tell them so.

Answer (score 8):

I've been on this site for 3 years and I've managed to earn 9 reputation so I know a thing or two about how people handle being told that high rep users are less likely to help if X.

Instead of telling the poster that the High rep users will be less likely to help them if their tone is bad, try helping the poster understand that programming languages usually don't execute incorrectly. It would also be helpful to show the poster the new code of conduct. It would probably help them if you showed them some examples of good questions and solid comments. It takes a while to figure out what a comment is actually supposed to be used for on Stack Exchange.

The poster's tone sounds like it's just coming from being super new to programming in general. This is what I'd expect a college student to say in their first month of their first programming class.

I actually heard of a lot of commentary like this when in my first matlab class.

It might also be helpful to look into what to do when someone is tilted. From my experience in gaming, you generally don't talk to tilted people till they get untilted. If you do have to talk to tilted people, you generally want to help them along with their thinking by asking questions and being patient. This is usually best done after their goal is achieved. On SO, I'd just suggest taking themselves out of the code for a bit by look at something 20 feet away for 20 seconds. That should help them cool off significantly.